# In Google Analytics, collect the site search query parameter only on a specific page

Tags: google-analytics, query-string, site-search

I've set up site-search for our main Google Analytics profile, which filters GET named "q". While this works nicely, it also collects data from our starting page (which contains a dealer locator which also uses the "q" parameter to search).

Is there any way to seperate two different search engines, which use the same query parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Can you change the app to use a different querystring name? Or in the GA tracking on the page, pass a custom page view that doesn't have that parameter?

If that's not possible, then have you tried creating a filter to change the querystring? It would be an "advanced" filter under "custom filter" on the filters screen. [Here's more information from Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

You can separate inbound query links (like referrers to your homepage) from your internal searches by integrating site search within your views. This way you're also not limited to GET queries but also POST.

There's more info on this feature here:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help my case, since both of the searches are internal and both of them use GET instead of POST.